# Write in Exfat Disk USB

Tags: exfat

I have a sandisk formatter in exfat, my ubuntu is in 22.04, and none of my users can write in this hard disk. Does anyone have a solution for me, I'm looking everywhere and I can't find anything. Except maybe a change in the fstab file, which caused me a corruption problem on reboot, so I had to reinstall ubuntu.

None of my modifications and even in root are applied to the hard disk.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Read `man mount`, the section called "`Mount options for fat`". Before editing `/etc/fstab`, read `man fstab`, and make a copy before you change it.

Comment: You can check your /etc/fstab changes with `umount` the SanDisk disk, then  `sudo mount -a`. You can fix errors before rebooting.